# Incorrect sum while calculating expression SQL

Tags: sql-server, expression, difference

For a report that I am creating I need to find the Shrink. The shrink is basically the difference. It is the input weight (user generated) subtracted by the SUM of the total weight (`OriginalQuantity_Stk`)

Currently I am using the expression

```
Sum(@InputWeight - [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) AS [Shrink]
```

I also tried to use

```
 Sum(@InputWeight - [WEIGHT]) AS [Shrink]
```

Because the grand total of the weight is already calculated:

```
Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
```

When the user runs the report they enter some information and one piece of information is the input weight. For example we will say they enter 20,000.
If the total weight adds up to 19,800, the Shrink should equal 200.

An example output would look like this:

Input Weight: 20,000
Product # | Weight | Shrink
1234      | 12,000 | 
1235      | 6,500  | 
1236      | 500    | 
1237      | 800    | 
--------------------------
TOTAL     |19,800  | 200

Let me know if that makes sense or not.

I am using Microsoft SQL Sever 2005.

Full code for reference:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 2.58;
SET @InputWeight = 20000;

SELECT DISTINCT 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2)) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / @InputWeight) AS [Yield]
   , Sum(@InputWeight - [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) AS [Shrink]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers [ARC] 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ([ARC].CustomerCode = '         904') 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate
   , [ARC].CustomerCode
 ORDER BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
```

Comment: sum((1200-19800)+(6500-19800)+(500-19800)+(800-19800)) is what you're doing I believe.

Comment: @xQbert that would make sense, do you know how to just take the grand total and use it?

Comment: Might be able to do it using a windowed function something like...  `@Inputweight - sum( [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) over (partition by   CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode)`   definitely would work as a CTE or sub query.  The problem is you need the sum before you can do the subtraction, but the query needs to process all records to have that sum.  So the only way to get the sum in advance is a subqery, cte, or window function(analytic).

Comment: @xQbert when I do that I get the error: "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses"

Comment: well the dirty answer (and possibly the only one which makes it less dirty) is CTE or subquery then  you have to have the sum result before you can select from it.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure that you want to take the sum of the weight minus the input value.

```
Sum([WEIGHT]) - @InputWeight AS [Shrink]
```

Or maybe it is

```
@InputWeight - Sum([WEIGHT]) AS [Shrink]
```

Comment: it is (at)inputweight - sum of weight. But if I do your second expression I get the error "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Why are you putting that in the group by? Just change the column and leave the group by alone.

Comment: I am using a service that doesn't allow me to directly edit the SQL. I can only input snippets of code or use existing fields. I can make it not go to the group by by using the expression "Sum((at)InputWeight - Sum([WEIGHT])) AS [Shrink]" but I get the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." ... This program makes it very difficult but I have to use it.

Comment: Yuck what a nightmare. Not sure what tool you are using but it sounds awful. I don't know how to tell you to fix the query since you can't actually fix the query. What I suggested will work from the t-sql side of things. I don't know how to force your tool or whatever to comply with standard t-sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pull your 'logic' outside of your 'aggregate'

For example:

```
@InputWeight - Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) AS [Shrink]
```

UPDATED:
I ran this locally:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Test
```

Results:

```
Id      Weight
1234    12000
1235    6500
1236    500
1237    800

DECLARE @other INT = 1000;
SELECT
    Id,
    SUM([Weight])
FROM #Test
GROUP BY Id
```

Results:

```
Id      (No column name)
1234    12000
1235    6500
1236    500
1237    800

SELECT
    @other - SUM([Weight]) AS [Shrink]
FROM #Test
GROUP BY Id
```

Results:

```
Shrink
-11000
-5500
500
200
```

Comment: If I do that I get the error "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause."

Comment: in the Shrink column. It is putting that expression in the group by and I guess that isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery should work. I still think a window function should work, but I'd have to play around with it more than I'm willing to without sample data/structure.

```
SELECT supplier
   , productcode
   , description1
   , boxes
   , unitofMeasure_Alt
   , weight
   , unitofMeasure_stk
   , [unit cost]
   , [total sales]
   , [avg. box weight]
   ,  yield/@inputweight as yield
   , @inputweight-shrink as shrink 
FROM (
SELECT 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2)) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] ) AS [Yield]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) AS [Shrink]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers [ARC] 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ([ARC].CustomerCode = '         904') 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate
   , [ARC].CustomerCode)) B
 ORDER BY 
     Supplier
```